# How do I change the destination of a new record in a database

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I'm currently messing around with Databases with sqlite3, I'm trying to find out how to add a record to a specific place in the list, rather than just to the bottom.

Comment: Tables don't have any inherent order, you can't put things in specific places. Ordering is done by using `ORDER BY` in queries.

Comment: Do you think you could elaborate?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AdamIsDweb I'm not sure how to say it any better. SQLite tables don't have any order. If your use of the table requires some order, add a column that represents the ordering criteria.